# How to find the PR with the most lines deleted OR added?

Tags: git, github

When we check git's PR in GitHub, we can see how many lines were added and deleted. e.g.

[image]

As we have many PRs, I like to sort the PR with the lines of code deleted OR added, so I know which PR contributed most to the code base.

How can I do that without the need to manually search through each PR?